# How to write explicitly, in spherical coordinates, a boundary problem that models the temperature

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

I am asked to write explicitly, in spherical coordinates, a boundary problem that models the temperature $u$ wih regard to the sun, considered nearly spherical, with radius R and surface temperatureT = 5777 K.
In our model, we disregard convection and other complicating
effects, and assume the temperature u in the interior of the star is stationary (no timedependence), a radial function (u = u(r)), and governed by the Poisson equation $\Delta u = f$.
Here, the source term f is a $C^∞$ function that models the heat production in the Sun due to nuclear fusion.

My model is the following:

$\Delta u= \frac{d^2}{dr^2}u+\frac{2}{r} \frac{d}{dr}u = f$

$u(R)=T=5777 K$

where $u(R)=T=5777 K$ is the Dirichlet boundary condition

The heat distribution of the Sun can be modelled by the Poisson equation:

$$ \Delta u = f$$

To write in spherical coordinates a boundary problem that models the temperature $u$ we can use the spherical Laplacian coordinates for the problem:

$$ \Delta u= \frac{d^2}{dr^2}u+\frac{2}{r} \frac{d}{dr}u = f$$

Since $u=u(r)$ is only a function of the radius the Beltrami operator can be neglected.

Is it correct in your opinion?